# What is the word for bright colors such as green?

Tags: colors

What does one call these bright colors such as pink, green, or yellow?  You see those in posters frequently.

Comment: Which 'bright colors'? Had you meant to include some images?

Comment: There are technical terms in color science which -might- capture what you informally describe as 'bright'. See [saturation, value or brightness, and lightness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Pick which colors match what you think as 'bright' and then see where they fit on those coordinate systems.

Answer (score 7):

If you are talking about the softer hues of pink, yellow, and green, those would be *pastels*:

[image]

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastel_%28color%29):

> **Pastels** or **pastel colors** are the family of colors which, when described in the HSV color space, have high value and low to intermediate saturation. The colors of this family are usually described as "soothing", "soft", "near neutral", "milky", "washed out", "desaturated", lacking strong chromatic content.
>
> Pink, mauve, and baby blue are typical pastel colors.

However, since you mentioned "bright" colors, I suspect you are referring to ***neons***:

[image]

Comment: Funny, only the green seems neon-y.  The orange is nearly cinnabar, the pink isn’t hot, and the blue is cyan.

Comment: They are sometimes called *day-glo* or *fluorescent*.

Comment: @tchrist - Great observation. (I didn't create the image, I just reused it.) For comparative purposes, these are labeled as [neon-colored tapes](http://craftysquid.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/allNEON.JPG?itok=hRAAqD0l).

Answer (score 2):

Does [this](http://www.infoplease.com/ipea/A0934307.html) help? Sample information given here. Please read the whole article about types of colors in the link I gave you.

> **Warm Colors**
>
> Warm colors are made with red, orange, yellow, or some combination of
>   these. Warm colors tend to make you think of sunlight and warmth.
>
> **Cool Colors**
>
> Cool colors are made with blue, green, purple, or some combination of
>   these. Cool colors might make you think of cool and peaceful things,
>   like winter skies and still ponds.

Comment: Actually, a combination of red and yellow produces green, which is not deemed a warm color at all.

Comment: @tchrist: ?? As far as I know, red and yellow make orange both in paint and in light.

Comment: Wait, I didn't notice that last night @TimLymington. Haha!

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean [vivid colors](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=vivid+colors&FORM=HDRSC2)?  These are extremely bright, flashy colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider the word "fluorescent".
It was mentioned above about pastel colors, but that comment is wrong. Pastel colors are soft.